# "Non vergognarti a chiedere" vs "Non vergognarti di chiedere"

Tags: prepositions

> If there's something you'd like to know, don't hesitate to ask me.

To express the idea of "don't hesitate **to** ask me", I wonder which preposition to use here, even though "di" seems more common with the verb "vergognare".

> ..., non vergognarti **a** chiedere.
>
> ..., non vergognarti **di** chiedere.

Comment: At [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vergognarsi) there is this example: *mi vergognavo di chiederglielo*.

Comment: Actually *to hesitate* means *esitare*, not *vergognarsi*...

Comment: *Vergognarsi* can be contructed with *di* or with *a*: in your case both are correct (see [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vergognarsi_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) at point 2.)

Comment: Rather then *vergognarsi* (which could stand, though) a better translation could be *esitare* or *aver timore*. The former requires *a*, the latter takes both *a* or *di*.

Answer (score 1):

The more common preposition is **di** according to [Google Ngram data](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vergognarsi%20di%2Cvergognarsi%20a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvergognarsi%20di%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvergognarsi%20a%3B%2Cc0) and (if it counts) to my ear.

I have to agree that using the verb **vergognarsi** in this case does sound odd, and I would prefer **esitare**, or maybe (more informal) **non farti problemi a chiedere**.

Comment: Actually it depends on the meaning! See [treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vergognarsi_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/). Google Ngram doesn't take into account the context...